# Digital signatures in MVC application Forms

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, digital-signature

I am having an requirement to show a digital signature box at the bottom of the registration form, which supervisor can sign it and check it.

Comment: Instead of lengthy "searched a lot/help me ASAP" it would be better to provide explanation what "digital signature" means in your case and what legal requirements you need to satisfy with it. Showing effort to solve (like list of possible solutions you've found or tried) would make post even better.

Answer (score 3):

[Disclosure: I work for CoSign]

As Alexei comments, the big issue is what do you mean by "digital signature?"

If you mean a simple digital representation of a person's graphical signature (a "fax signature"), then you can use a Javascript library. The signer would use either the mouse or a finger to "sign." Eg, see Prof. Thomas J Bradley's [signature-pad](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/) jQuery plugin.

But a simple "fax signature" does not give you assurance of:

1. **Identification.** How do you know that the person who claims to be John Doe really was John Doe?
2. **Document integrity.** How do you know (and prove in court) that the set of data (or document) signed by the person was not changed from the time he signed it? -- Neither changed on purpose, nor changed by error, by a bug, etc?
3. **Non-reputability of the signature.** If John Doe later says, "it wasn't me who signed," how do you prove that it must have been him? This is not the same as the Identification issue.

The answer to issues 1-3 is to use open, standard PKI-based digital signatures. My company, [CoSign](http://www.arx.com), and many others make digital signature systems. Digital signatures do **not** require smart cards if they are server or cloud based.

Digital signatures are the proven, state of the art answer to all these issues. Implementing digital signatures used to be difficult. Now, by using server or cloud based secure signature creation devices and modern [digital signature APIs](http://www.arx.com/digital-signatures/developers), it is easy to add real digital signatures to your app.

Comment: look at some cloud based applications, signatures associated to a login. it can be pre-set images or an input from signature-pad. or if you are using an tablet or any other touch devices, you can simply sign using your stylus

Comment: I agree with Larry, assurance is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser can support HTML5, then the best option is HTML5 canvas

You can place a HTML5-canvas for signature,

Also you can provide a sign button which loads the predefined signature for supervisor login.

If you are using any device for signing, the device output image can be set to canvas image.

Please refer this article, showing paintbrush using HTML5-canvas
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/427422/Paint-Brush-Application-Using-HTML5-Canvas

Comment: +0: it would be nice if you explain what is the question you are answering as there no single definition of "digital signature"...

Comment: look at some cloud based applications, signatures associated to a login. it can be pre-set images or an input from signature-pad. or if you are using an tablet or any other touch devices, you can simply sign using your stylus

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you were hoping to provide search link for - indeed first results point to [digital signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) Wikipedia article that describes Larry K answer and nowhere close to yours... There is nothing wrong with your answer, but since the question is did not specify if OP indeed mean digital signing or simply image or even single checkbox "I agree" it is unclear to readers what your answer relates to.